# How to list openstack all projects' quotas?

Tags: openstack

I'm new to openstack ,and now I want to export a table which including all projects' quotas, including instance numbers,vcpus,memory,volume size...

how could I make it(Queens) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openstack quota show` command to list your tenant resources.
Please remember to source the open-rc file before typing above command.
For more commands, you can refer to [Openstack docs](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/admin/quotas.html).